# EasyVPN client Access mutiple subnet behind cisco 5510

Tags: cisco-vpn

I need help with the following scenario
Main network ASA 5510 (one inside 192.168.10.1 connection and one outside connection). This ASA 5510 connect to switch 3570 with 3 VLANS configured (192.168.10.0, 10.10.11.0, 10.10.12.0). On the remote site I have ASA5505 ( 10.10.13.0) connected to this ASA5510 through EZVPN, but all it can see is the 192.168.10.0 subnet. What do I need to do to get the subnet 10.10.13.0 to see all 3 internal subnets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update you protected networks on the Main network's VPN profile to include your other two subnets.

If they are already in the config, you might need to check your nat0's and ACLs.

Also, if you need help with either of those, can you post the pertinent parts of your Main network config so I'm not guessing at how you have things setup - please remember to sanitize them before you post :)